# ii cant get into my gmail account forgot password

Tags: applications

I have a gmail I forgot my password and google won't help. I've reset my tablet but did press backup is there anyway I can get this important gmail

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow these steps to reset your password: https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/2402620?visit_id=0-636165652605527813-2656708135&p=ar_other_problems_username&rd=1

If none of them work for you, you probably can't regain access to your Google account.